# How to resolve error regarding null value passed in Guid property?

Tags: c#, nullable, guid

I am trying to post JSON as which is supposed to work as a request body for a filter/search , so null value is allowed:

```
{
    "Guid":"",
    "FirstName":"",
    "LastName":""
}
```

And, the DTO class is:

```
Public class PersonDto
{
       public Guid Guid { get; set; }
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And, I get this `"Error converting value \"\" to type 'System.Guid'`, I tried keep Guid as Guid? but that also is not working

Comment: You're sending an empty string, not a null value. An empty string is not a valid Guid. You can send `"Guid":null` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`""` is not a valid guid. Strongly typed objects are always nullable so you don't need `Guid?`

You can use `null` or you can use a proper guid, but not an empty string.

```
{
  Guid: null,
  FirstName: "Larry",
  LastName: "Jones"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the property as `Guid?` and pass `Guid: null` as suggested by @JDHannan.

Or you could mantain not nullable property as `Guid` and pass a default guid `"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"` and check for it in your code.

```cs
if (filter.Guid != default(Guid)) {
}
```

I found that this solution best fit when you use a drop down as UI for the filter.

Anyway, I suggest to use a separate DTO for filtering (eg. `PersonFilterDTO`), so you could enrich the filtering options independently from the `PersonDTO`.